# emulators connection using TCP

Tags: android, tcp, ip, emulation

hy again!
I'm trying to connect two emulators running as server and client on the same PC.The thing is that one of them is inside a virtual machine.What addresses should I use for each of the emulators in order to connect between them?
I'm using a TCP based connection!
The first emulator is running on Windows 7
The second one inside the Vmware is on Xp
The IP of my PC inside the network is 192.168.71.1
Really gratefull if u answer.Thx!!

Comment: It's good practice to edit your original post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584944/connecting-emulators) from 5 hours ago rather than add a new question with a few more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you'd want to use the localhost address (127.0.0.1).  Set the server up to listen and once it is up and running have the client connect and you should be good to go.  (Make sure the port you use matches, obviously.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 3):

A few more details would help:

- What is the IP address of the VM?
- Is it using NAT, bridged networking, or what?
- Do you really need to run the 2nd emulator inside a VM - this complicates networking.

**UPDATE: Multiple emulators on 1 machine (no VM)**
You can launch another emulator from the command-line, using /emulator -avd . You'll need to create a second AVD for this to work. I use Linux, so can't give the exact details for Windows.

**UPDATE: Communication between main machine and VM with android emulator**
I believe the emulator only listens on 127.0.0.1 for server sockets, so remote machines can't connect in - this is certainly the case for the debug sockets it uses. However, you can set up port forwarding using a similar method discussed in [Remote debugging with Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754162/remote-debugging-with-android-emulator)

It's good that you're using bridged networking, as NAT would stop the VM getting inbound connections, so the emulator would have no hope.

**UPDATE #2: Port forwarding**
You can set up port forwarding between sockets on the local machine and on the emulator, using [adb forward](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports). It might also be worth looking at [Communication between Android Emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044479/comunication-between-android-emulators), there appears to be an undocumented emulator switch -shared-net-id that could help.

Hope this helps

Phil Lello

Comment: Yes,is using NAT.No,it is not necesarlly to run the second emulator inside VM,but other  way there is?Cause I have only one PC....could I run two emulators inside one enviroment.If yes,how?Thank u

Comment: Sorry the connection is bridge.But I'm interesting in finding out how can I have two emulators on the same machine:)

Comment: I'll post my comment as an update on the original answer... not enough space/format in comments.

Comment: Supposing I run  two emulators inside one machine(no VM),what are the addresses I should use?I know each of the emulators is behind a different virtual router

Comment: I've updated again, now with details on port forwarding & shared-net-id, which should put both emulators on the same virtual net.